# How to conditional format a row based on date range

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

1. I'd like to set up a conditional format to highlight a row where I'm currently at in my trip. Ie a date that is greater than or equal to today but not for following sections of my trip.
2. With this current trip section row, I'd like to select a cell in a corresponding column and multiply it by the date difference between the start date of that section and today's.

[image: WA106810 question example]

Answer (score 0):

> a conditional format to highlight a row where im currently at in my trip. Ie a date that is greater than or equal to today but not for following sections of my trip.

Clear formatting from Columns A:B (presumably), select ColumnsA:B and Format, Conditional formatting..., Format cells if... **Custom formula is** and:

```
=$A1=index($A:$A,iferror(match(TODAY(),$A:$A,0),match(today(),$A:$A,1)))
```

Then select fill of choice and <kbd>Done</kbd>.

Set spreadsheet to the appropriate time zone.